# Замена значений на NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Работаю с таблицей данных, в которых есть как положительные, так и отрицательные значения.

Как в определённом столбце заменить все положительные значения на `NaN`?

Пробовал так:

```
df.loc[df['days_employed'] > 0, 'days_employed'] = "NaN"
```

Но мне выдало ошибку.

Comment: Я почти не знаком с питоном, но можно ли хранить в данной таблице значения типа NaN? Но полагаю, что в ячейку таблицы нельзя записать данный тип данных. Возможно стоит конвертировать в строку данное значение и только потом писать

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: у меня есть таблица, где в одном столбце ('days_employed') хранятся данные в о стаже огромного кол-ва сотрудников. тип данных float64. Но данные есть как положительные числа так и отрицательные. Задача состоит в том, что все положительные числа заменить на NaN, т.е. чтобы остались только либо NaN либо отрицательное числа

Comment: @АртёмКрашенинников, для таких данных [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1233965/211923) должен подойти

Comment: А что за ошибку то выдаёт? Я попробовал в Google Colab, всё прекрасно работает, никакой ошибки не выдаёт. Разве что NaN у вас текстовый получается, но сама эта строка ошибок не содержит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1 -1  3
2  0  4
3  5 -1

In [55]: df.loc[df["a"].gt(0), "a"] = np.nan

In [56]: df
Out[56]: 
     a  b
0  NaN  2
1 -1.0  3
2  0.0  4
3  NaN -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще ошибки быть никакой не должно, за исключением случая, когда вы пытаетесь проделать эту операцию несколько раз (либо если у вас в столбце уже были строковые данные по какой-то причине):

```
df.loc[df['days_employed'] > 0, 'days_employed'] = "NaN"
df.loc[df['days_employed'] > 0, 'days_employed'] = "NaN"
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Если использовать `np.nan`, что более правильно, ошибки не будет:

```
df.loc[df['days_employed'] > 0, 'days_employed'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['days_employed'] > 0, 'days_employed'] = np.nan
```

Разницы между `> 0` и `.gt(0)` никакой нет.